# Why can I access the secure part of my website without the certificate?

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to setup [Certificate based Client Authentication](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol).

To do this, I created a CA root certificate (called `pi.key` and `pi.crt`) and then signed a client certificate (called `Hairy.key` and `Hairy.csr`) and also created a `Hairy.crt` and `Hairy.p12` file. [I followed these instructions](https://gist.github.com/mtigas/952344).

I've added the `Hairy.p12` file to Google Chrome following [these instructions](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/portal/articles/1211541-install-client-digital-certificate---windows-using-chrome).

Next I added the following to my `httpd.conf` (at `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`):

```
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-keys/pi.crt

<Location /InternalAccess/NetData>
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
</Location>
```

and restarted the server with `service apache2 restart`.

According to [the Apache website](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) (the second heading), this should allow anyone to access most of the website, but only me (whoever has the `Hairy.p12` certificate installed) to access `/InternalAccess/NetData/`.

To test it, I opened it in Firefox and was able to access the page. I was expecting to get a 401 not authorised error.

I then tried to use [this page](http://www.garex.net/apache/) but it's quite old (Apache 1, talking about Netscape!) and didn't clarify anything I did wrong.

So how can I limit the path `/InternalAccess/NetData/` to clients with a certificate which I've signed?

Comment: Apache docs say that the [SSLVerifyClient directive contexts are server config, virtual host, directory, and .htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslverifyclient). Probably you need to put the directive in one of those contexts instead of in a Location context.

Comment: @DiogenesdeLight No, that's still accessible on both browsers.

Comment: I found [this](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/5216738) for you. See if it helps. If not, I'd suggest you post your entire (updated) config.

Comment: @DiogenesdeLight No, they seem to have the same configuration as I do. My `apache.conf` is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24656601/ and my `sites-enabled/*.conf` is just one file: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24656613/

Comment: Your upload has `SSLVerifyClient optional`, but your post has `SSLVerifyClient require`. Which one are you using?

Comment: @DiogenesdeLight In this case, it's `require` - it doesn't work with either - sorry. Thanks for the help - I know how frustrating newbies is.

Comment: Ok. I'll leave you with three thoughts then: 1) consider using curl -V instead of browsers for initial testing to rule out browser caching and to view the handshake, 2) check your apache logs for more information on the transaction, and 3) [activate debug logging for ssl](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DebuggingSSLProblems).